# Tensorflow fit, can you set weights/bias on specific elements in train data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Let's assume I feed my `TF model` a 3D `array`

e.x. with the `input_shape = (3,3)`

```
X_data =      [ [[3,4,-1] , [2,2,-8] , [4,7,0]] , 
                [[...] , [...] , [5,10,-15]] ,
                 ... ]
```

`tf.fit()` function has an argument `class_weight`, but from examples I have seen, that it only separates the weights between output labels ( in my case 0 or 1 ) in `Y_data = [ 0, 1, 1 ...]`, thus to make more notice to one, or the other output.

**But what I need** is for training func. to make more notice to some data in the input.

e.x. in the `X_data`, I want training function to *consider and be more biased* about the last `array` in 2D `array` in the train data => `[4,7,0]`, `[5,10,-15]` and so on.

Or, e.x. To *consider and be more biased* about the first element in each of the `arrays` => `3, 2 and 4` and so on.

**Is that possible?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom loss function to do that:

```
loss = 0.6 * loss(a[0]) + 0.2 * loss(a[1]) + 0.2 * loss(a[2])
```

Try something like this formula.